# How to get the text of all child elements in a list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

In the below pic I need to get the text of all the tspan elements which comes under the highlighted g tag (Scripting using Katalon Studio)

```
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels " data-z-index="7">
<text x="212.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 13</tspan></text>
<text x="266.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 14</tspan></text>
<text x="319.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 15</tspan></text>
<text x="373.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 16</tspan></text>
<text x="426.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 17</tspan></text>
<text x="480.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 18</tspan></text>
<text x="533.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 19</tspan></text>
<text x="587.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 20</tspan></text>
<text x="640.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 21</tspan></text>
<text x="694.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 22</tspan></text>
<text x="747.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 23</tspan></text>
<text x="801.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 24</tspan></text>
<text x="854.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1">
<tspan>Aug 25</tspan></text>
<text x="908.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="183" opacity="1"><tspan>Aug 26</tspan></text>
</g>
```

[image: need to get the text of all the tspan elements which comes under the highlighted g tag]

That is I need to get the dates Aug 12, Aug 13, Aug 14 etc in a list and get the text of it .(The x value in text tag is dynamic and keeps varying for every session)
I am using Katalon Studio for scripting.

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Edit : (did not work)
public class VerifyChartData {

```
private static void compareChartDataWithTable(){
    
    TestObject selector_datapoints = new TestObject().addProperty(
    'xpath', com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType.EQUALS, '//div[@id="container"]/div/*[local-name()="svg"]/*[local-name()="g" and contains(@class, "highcharts-axis-labels") and contains(@class, "highcharts-xaxis-labels")]',
    true)
     
         List<WebElement> datapoints = WebUI.findWebElements(selector_datapoints, 30)
         
         KeywordUtil.logInfo(datapoints.get(0).toString())
             
         
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you try something? Show your code?

Comment: @JaSON Yes, I tried but it didn't work. Edited with my code

Comment: @YS04 Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry for adding screenshot. Now I have updated the details with HTML code.

Comment: What is the result of your code above?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with below code -

private static void compareChartDataWithTable(){

```
TestObject selector_datapoints = new TestObject().addProperty(
        'xpath', com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType.EQUALS, '//div[@id="container"]/div/*[local-name()="svg"]/*[local-name()="g" and contains(@class, "highcharts-axis-labels") and contains(@class, "highcharts-xaxis-labels")]',
        true)


List<WebElement> datapoints = WebUI.findWebElements(selector_datapoints, 30)
for(int i = 0; i < datapoints.size; i++){
    KeywordUtil.logInfo(datapoints[i].getText())
    }
```

}
Result :
2020-08-27 12:25:41.585 DEBUG testcase.Check SP Keywords Dashboard - 5: ******.VerifyChartData.compareChartDataWithTable()
2020-08-27 12:25:46.641 INFO com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil - Aug 13
Aug 14
Aug 15
Aug 16
Aug 17
Aug 18
Aug 19
Aug 20
Aug 21
Aug 22
Aug 23
Aug 24
Aug 25
Aug 26
2020-08-27 12:25:46.643 INFO k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - ******.VerifyChartData.compareChartDataWithTable is PASSED